# Install dotnet core on Linux Mint 19

Tags: .net, .net-core, linux-mint

After following Microsoft tutorials on how to install dotnet core on linux mint 19 i got stuck to :

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.4
```

I got prompted that it needs *dotnet-runtime-2.0.5* to be installed and so i executed :

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-runtime-2.0.5
```

And i got

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   dotnet-runtime-2.0.5 : Depends: libicu55 but it is not installable
```

So the problem is that i cannot install this libicu55 because it doesn't exist.
How can i fix this?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint_version_history) says that Linux Mint 19 is compatible with Ubuntu 18.04. So you could possibly grab the package from there? (Or maybe there's a different libicu available that you could use instead, and force apt-get to ignore dependencies? I don't know Linux Mint.)

Comment: Microsoft intends to limit .NET Core 2.0/2.1 on a small set of Linux OS, https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.1/2.1-supported-os.md so you should use a supported version of Mint (17 or 18).

Comment: With mint 19 I installed dotnet with 'sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.2'. No unmet dependencies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Microsoft has its own package source for ubuntu now. The official download page has detailed instructions:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/linux-package-manager/ubuntu19-04/sdk-current

The following deb package installs the package source in your system:

```
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/19.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

After an `sudo apt-get update` you can simply install your favorite SDK (e.g. 3.0) via

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-3.0
```

The major benefit: you get updates and its easier to upgrade to the next major release.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'll keep this in mind for future installations!

Answer (score 4):

you may grab the package from here and install manually:

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/

Did you also try this way?

Download from : https://www.microsoft.com/net/download

Then:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/dotnet

cd Downloads

tar zxf dotnet-sdk-2.0.3-linux-x64.tar.gz -C $HOME/dotnet

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet
```

Verify your installation:

```
dotnet --version
```

Comment: Downloading the package from the first link worked, i had already tried the second method with no success though.

Comment: I would add for `Linux Mint 20` I opened `sudo nano .bash_profile` and add the following lines: `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet` and `export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/.dotnet`

Answer (score 1):

That package isn't valid for Ubuntu 18.04, there for it isn't valid for Mint 19.  Just run the following to get the right version installed and you should be good.

```
sudo apt install libicu60
```

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libicu60&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all

And just to add to clarify, this is in fact outlined in the official Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x#ubuntu)

Comment: +1 - ICU document that ["applications that are built with one version of ICU must continue to run without change with later versions of the ICU shared library"](http://userguide.icu-project.org/design#TOC-ICU-Binary-Compatibility:-Using-ICU-as-an-Operating-System-Level-Library).

Comment: I got prompted that libicu60 is already installed, student18 answer worked for me though.